# React Hooks only update state on form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I've been at this all morning and can't figure out how to update my state correctly using `useState`.

I have a single controlled user input with `name`. When a user enters text and submits I would like to take the input value and push that to another state object `namesList` and map over that array in a child component.

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

import NameInputList from './NameInputList';

const NameInputContainer = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [namesList, setNamesList] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setName(value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNamesList(prevState => [...prevState, name]);
    setName('');
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          id="name"
          label="Enter New Name"
          variant="outlined"
          value={name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>
      {namesList.length > 0 && <NameInputList names={namesList} />}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default NameInputContainer;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const NameInputList = ({ names }) => {
  console.log('child component names: ', names);
  const generateKey = val => {
    return `${val}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {names.map((name, index) => ( // <--- Adding the index here seems to resolve the problem. I want to say the error was happening based on issues with having Unique keys. 
        <li key={generateKey(name + index)}>{name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

NameInputList.propTypes = {
  names: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
};

NameInputList.defaultProps = {
  names: []
};

export default NameInputList;
```

Seems like when I submit the first time the child component gets the correct value and renders as expected. When I go to input a new name there's a rerender on every `handleChange`. I'm not sure how to consistently: enter text > submit input > update `namesList` > render updated `namesList` in child component without `handleChange` breaking the functionality.

[image]

Comment: We should see what's inside `NameInputList` ^^

Comment: The re-render will happen as a new copy of `namesList` will be provided as props even if its content doesn't change. Could you share the code for `NameInputList` ?

Comment: Sorry I think I figured it out, it's working as expected when I add an index to the map. I think it's working as expected and it was my failure to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to that, as `namesList` prop is an array, a new copy will be sent for each parent re-render. Hence it's comparison will always be false and React will trigger a re-render of the child.

You can prevent the re-render by doing this :

```
export default React.memo(NameInputList, function(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.names.join("") === nextProps.names.join("");
});
```

This will ensure that `NameInputList` only re-renders when the contents of `namesList` actually change.

Comment: I like where this solution is taking me, and looking up memo looks very promising. Unfortunately, I'm still running into unique key errors. I've removed the index argument and not using that in the `generateKey()`. Right now I have 

`export function NameInputList({ names }) {...}`

`const MemoizedNameInputList = React.memo(NameInputList, (prevProps, nextProps) => {return prevProps.names.join('') === nextProps.names.join('');});

export default MemoizedNameInputList;`

But I'm not sure how to resolve the unique key error. idk if the NPM package `shortid` is a proper solution

Comment: Ideally just passing key as `${name}_${index}` should be sufficient. THis will be always unique